# c++ error int i = 0 not working

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization, int

For some reason in my c++ code, int i= 0 is not working. In debug mode, it stores 1024 into i after it goes out of scope. When I try to declare it to 0, it doesn't work. i is not a global variable.

```
void CCurrent::findPeaks()//this checks for peaks in the FFT
{
  int localPeakIndx[256]={};
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<DATASIZE/2;i++)
  {
    if(magnitude[i]>m_currentValues.AverageMagnitude*3) {
        localPeakIndx[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
  }
  //i should be out of scope
  int startIndx;
  int endIndx;
  int i = 0;//why does it equal 1024?????? debug*
```

Comment: Where is your proof that it is 1024?

Comment: "In debug mode, it stores 1024 into i after it goes out of scope" - how do you know that, and why are you trying to use its value after it goes out of scope?

Comment: Also, that second `i` is different than the one you used in the loop.

Comment: I know it is 1024 because it says it is 1024 using visual studio 2010 in debug mode.

Comment: @Bobby First, a debugger is not proof.  You could be misusing the debugger, you could be debugging a release build, who knows.  If you want proof, how about a simple `cout << i;` after you declared it?

Comment: If `int i = 0;` doesn't give you a compiler error then you have declared an `i` and initialized it to 0. If you want proof, try and divide another number by it.

Comment: Here is proof https://imageshack.com/i/iqyWLCdrp

Comment: @Bobby - All that picture shows you is that your debugger is either bad, or some other issue.  It does *not* prove that i is not 0.  What is proof is you displaying the value using `cout` or some other means.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Another _integer_ number. Float will be happily divided by `0` :).

Comment: @AlexD Yes, but *any* other integer value will fail fast if `i` is 0. :)

Comment: I have added an answer that I think is the root cause and some code that will show it. I agree with the other posters here that think its just a debugger display thing and not a problem with your program.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by "int i= 0 is not working" and "it stores 1024 into i after it goes out of scope". That description is unrealistic and most likely does not take place. After `int i = 0` the value of `i` will be seen as `0`, not as `1024`.

What you have to keep in mind in this case is that your program has two `i` variables: one local to `for` cycle and one declared further down in the surrounding block. These are two different, completely unrelated variables.

Now, MS Visual Studio debugger will show you the values of all variables declared in the current block, even if the execution has not yet reached their point of declaration. Expectedly, variables whose declaration (and initialization) point has not been reached yet are shown with indeterminate (uninitialized) values.

Apparently, this is exactly what happens in your case. Your are looking at the value of outer `i` before its point of declaration and initialization. Even though name `i` is not yet visible immediately after the `for` cycle from the language point of view, the debugger will nevertheless give you "early access" to the outer `i`. The garbage value of that `i` at that point just happened to be `1024` in your experiment.

Note that there's certain definitive logic in this behavior. In general case it is not correct to assume that a local object does not exist *above* the point of its declaration. Being located *above* the point of declaration in *spatial* terms does not necessarily mean being located *before* the point of declaration in *temporal* terms, which becomes clear once you start using such beautiful feature of the language as `goto`.

For example, this piece of code

```
{
  int *p = NULL;

above:
  if (p != NULL) {
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    goto out;
  }

  int i = 10;
  p = &i;
  goto above;

out:;
}
```

is legal and has perfectly defined behavior. It supposed to output the valid initialized value of `i` through a valid pointer `p`, even though the output takes place *above* the `i`'s point of declaration. I.e. it is possible to end up in the situation when the current execution point is located above the object declaration, yet the object already exists and holds a determinate value. To help you with debugging in such situations the debugger allows you to see the values of all objects that may potentially exist at that point, which includes all objects declared in the current block. In general case the debugger does not know which objects formally exist already and which do not, so it just lets you see everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small refinement of what was already said:

The "outer i" is given space on the stack along with all other local variables when the function is entered.

Since the "outer i" hasn't been given a value before the end of the `for` loop, the debugger is looking on the stack where the value for `i` *ought* to be, and showing you what happens to be there.

This comes from the fact that local variables are not initialized.

I bet if you tried to access i from C before the declaration, the compiler would tag *that* as an error.  But the debugger doesn't have such scruples.